# Stackpanel/Itemscontrol Databinding

Tags: c#, itemscontrol, stackpanel

I have this XAML:

```
 <ItemsControl x:Name="recentSearches"
               Margin="0,65,0,0">
               <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                   <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                         <TextBlock Text="{Binding q}"
                                TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                Foreground="AliceBlue"
                                Padding="2,6,2,2"
                                Margin="12,-6,12,0"
                                FontSize="20" />
                      </DataTemplate>
                 </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

and this code behind:

```
private void showLatestSearches()
        {
            if (fmn.checkLatestSearchesExtistence())
            {
                List<RecentSearchItem> recent = new List<RecentSearchItem>();
                List<String> l = fmn.readLatestSearches();
                for (int i = 0; i <= l.Count-1; i += 1)
                {
                    RecentSearchItem r = new RecentSearchItem();
                    r.q = l[i];
                    r.generalbg = grau;
                    recent.Add(r);
                }
                recentSearches.DataContext = recent;
            }
        }
```

the object called fmn reads a .txt from the isolated storage. 
But why doesn't anything show up with this StackPanel?

Comment: Have you tried running your app and having a look with http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

`ItemsControl.ItemsSource` has to be bound to a collection, for notifications the best would be `ObservableCollection<T>`.

You are setting the DataContext at the last possible minute, a better way would be to set 
DataContext to a ViewModel, could be place where you create your View.

```
public class Form :UserControl
{
  DataContext = new YourViewModel() ;
}
```

In XAML:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding SearchesCollection}"
```

`SearchesCollection` would be a property in `YourViewModel` of type `ObservableCollection<string>`. Whenever you add a new item to `SearchesCollection` the View updates.

[This Databinding Tutorial](http://miteshsureja.blogspot.ie/2011/07/binding-observablecollection-to-listbox.html) should help.

Comment: I tried doing it like this `<ItemsControl x:Name="recentSearches"
                                      ItemsSource="recent"
                                      Margin="0,65,0,0">` but it still didn't work.

Comment: That isn't binding. In my answer: `ItemsSource="{Binding SearchesCollection}"`

Comment: Sorry, I meant `<ItemsControl x:Name="recentSearches"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding recent}"
                                      Margin="0,65,0,0">` but I still don't see anything. Is it not possible to bind it to a simple List?

Comment: You need an ObservableCollection. Look at the linked tutorial in my answer.

Comment: I know how to create and bind ListBoxes. I made ListBoxes without observable collections and it worked. So, is it not possible in a StackPanel?

Comment: Um, the link doesn't show how to make listboxes. It shows how to add items to a Listbox. It is more or less the same idea with ItemsControl. In your case it should create a new Textblock.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Lews Therin I managed to finally bind my data to the stackpanel:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="recentSearches"
              ItemsSource="{Binding recent}"
              Background="{Binding generalbg}"
              Margin="0,65,0,0" Tap="recentSearches_Tap">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding q}"
                                               Foreground="{Binding foreground}"
                                               TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                               Padding="2,6,2,2"
                                               Margin="12,-6,12,0"
                                               FontSize="20" />
                     </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
 </ItemsControl>
```

and the code behind:

```
private void showLatestSearches()
{
    if (fmn.checkLatestSearchesExtistence())
    {
        List<RecentSearchItem> recent = new List<RecentSearchItem>();
        List<String> l = fmn.readLatestSearches();
        for (int i = 0; i <= l.Count-1; i += 1)
        {
            RecentSearchItem r = new RecentSearchItem();
            r.q = l[i];
            r.generalbg = grau;
            r.foreground = blau;
            recent.Add(r);
        }
        recentSearches.ItemsSource = recent;
    }
}
```

this works, but unfortunately there seems to be no way to determine, which TextBox is tapped, when one is tapped.

Comment: This isn't a good way. Look at Viewmodels. What do you mean tapped?

Comment: When I tap on an item from the stackpanel, I can build an event handler for it, but there seems to be no way to know which item from the stackpanel was tapped.